# Unable to get Jasmine working with basic library

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine

I'm new to using Jasmine and Grunt (and StackOverflow). I'm trying to setup the most basic of projects. However, when I run my grunt task, I get an error that says:

```
Running "jasmine:testShared" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS

>> Error: notloaded: Module name "../" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded at
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\_SpecRunner.html:21
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:12 v
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:26 h
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:31
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\node_modules\glob\examples\g.js:1
>> Error: notloaded: Module name "../" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
>> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded at
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\_SpecRunner.html:21
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:12 v
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:26 h
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\.grunt\grunt-contrib-jasmine\require.js:31
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\node_modules\glob\examples\usr-local.js:1
>> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module at
>> ..\..\C:\Tests\jasmine\node_modules\glob\glob.js:37
>> Error caught from PhantomJS. More info can be found by opening the Spec Runner in a browser.
Warning: SyntaxError: Parse error Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The code for this project can be found [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8AFA7F1143FA366B!107&authkey=!AF6zwMN3jfXk0ug&ithint=file%2C.zip). My file structure looks like this:

```
/jasmine
 /node_modules
 /shared
   /modules
     myModule.js
   /tests
     /unit
       myModule.tests.js
 /tasks
   /options
     jasmine.js
     protractor.js
   test_task.js
 _SpecRunner.html
 gruntfile.js
 package.json
```

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "~0.9.0",
    "glob":"~4.0.3",
    "grunt":"~0.4.0",
    "grunt-cli":"~0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-connect":"0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine":"~0.6.5",
    "grunt-protractor-runner":"1.0.1",
    "grunt-start-webdriver":"0.0.2",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs":"0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core":"2.0.0",
    "jasmine-node":"2.0.0-beta3",
    "load-grunt-tasks":"0.2.x",
    "lodash":"~2.4.1",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.7-14",
    "selenium-webdriver":"2.42.1",       
    "time-grunt":"~0.3.2"
  }
}
```

My gruntfile.js file looks like this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var config = {
        name: 'MyApp',
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        baseDir: '.'
    };

    // load all grunt task details
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);    

    // load task definitions
    grunt.loadTasks('tasks');

    // Utility function to load plugin settings into config
    function loadConfig(config,path) {
        require('glob').sync('*', {cwd: path}).forEach(function(option) {
            var key = option.replace(/\.js$/,'');
            // If key already exists, extend it. It is your responsibility to avoid naming collisions
            config[key] = config[key] || {};
            grunt.util._.extend(config[key], require(path + option)(config,grunt));
        });
    }

    // Merge that object with what with whatever we have here
    loadConfig(config,'./tasks/options/');

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-start-webdriver');    
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');

    // pass the config to grunt
    grunt.initConfig(config);  
};
```

myModule.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash');
_.mixin({
  'myFunction' : function(s) {
    return 'Hello ' + s; 
  }
});

module.exports = _;
```

myModule.tests.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('myModule', function() {
    it('should work', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

test_task.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
    grunt.registerTask('test-shared', [
        'jasmine:testShared'
    ]);
};
```

jasmine.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  return {
       testShared: {
      src: "shared/modules/*.js",
      options: {
        specs: "shared/tests/unit/**.tests.js",
        vendor: "node_modules/**/*.js",
        template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs')
        }
      }
  };
};
```

protractor.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  return {
       testShared: {
      options: {
        configFile: "shared/tests/unit/config.js"
        }
      }
  };
};
```

I've spent two days on this. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I feel like I've followed the examples online. I feel like there is something stupid I'm overlooking. Can someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to diagnose without a running example but that error is caused by RequireJS. It happens when you do `require('something')` without having loaded it. Loading is asynchronous so you either need to do `require['lodash'], function(_) { do stuff }`. Or the preferred `define` syntax:

```
define([
    'lodash'
], function(_) {
    'use strict';

    _.mixin({
        myFunction: function(s) {
            return 'Hello ' + s; 
        }
    });

    return _;
});
```

With a test you would typically use the same structure and pull in the module you are testing in the `define`. You would set it up so the path to required files is the same as in the app.

To help more we need a running example.

My colleague made a good boilerplate using grunt/jasmine/requirejs maybe you can get some good practices from there: https://github.com/mderrick/backbone-boilerplate

Your directory structure is quite confusing have you considered simplifying it?
 - Use a single Gruntfile.js - don't fragment unless your project is very big

```
index.html
Gruntfile.js
app/
test/
```

That is all you really need to get going. In app it could look something like:

```
app/app.js <-- entry point
app/modules/...
```

Comment: How can I get you a running example? Do you want a .zip file?

Comment: I uploaded the code here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8AFA7F1143FA366B!107&authkey=!AF6zwMN3jfXk0ug&ithint=file%2c.zip. Just run npm install after you unzip it.

Comment: It has something to do with require and phantomjs. I feel like I got a little further with this build. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8AFA7F1143FA366B!107&authkey=!AF6zwMN3jfXk0ug&ithint=file%2c.zip

Comment: Run a server from inside your folder and then go to http://<yourserver>/_SpecRunner.html and debug from there. If you look at your spec runner you have 100s of node files being pulled in there - seems like there is something from with your Grunt task config - you should only have about 5 jasmine ones from .grunt/ and then your own files. Your directory structure is very confusing is there a reason why you have done it? Normally it is something like what I have put in answer above (in a sec) ^^

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "run a server from inside your folder"? My directory structure is this manner because I'm creating a library that I want to share with Node.js and my front-end. Some business logic if you will. That's why my directory is structured this way. Because its business logic, its also why I'm trying to figure out how to write some tests with Jasmine but minimizing the overhead.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1

Comment: I feel like I'm closer. Yet, not there. The latest version of my code can be seen here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8AFA7F1143FA366B!109&authkey=!ABy7xuGtOn-osko&ithint=file%2c.zip. The big difference is the addition of grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs. Now I'm getting a slightly different error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have not figured this out. I wish I could figure out why I can't get what seems like a very simple example of using requirejs with jasmine and grunt to work.

Comment: Usually requirejs seems to be a hastle with angular. Most people seem to go with browserify instead with its commonjs require style.